# OnClickListener doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have one screen with two spinners. The choices in the second spinner depend on the user choice in the first spinner.

Here is my code:

For the first spinner:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.oman_states));

 final MaterialBetterSpinner materialDesignSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner)
                findViewById(R.id.states_list);       // states spinner

        materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

for the second spinner:

```
  final MaterialBetterSpinner materialDesignSpinner2 = (MaterialBetterSpinner)
                findViewById(R.id.hospitals_list);
```

and I implemented the following listener in the second spinner:

```
materialDesignSpinner2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (materialDesignSpinner.getText().toString() == getString(R.string.muscat)) {

                    ArrayAdapter<String> muscatHospitals = new ArrayAdapter<>(v.getContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.muscat_hospitals));

                    materialDesignSpinner2.setAdapter(muscatHospitals);
                } else if (materialDesignSpinner.getText().toString() == getString(R.string.albatna)) {

                    ArrayAdapter<String> albatnaHospitals = new ArrayAdapter<>(v.getContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.albatan_hospitals));

                    materialDesignSpinner2.setAdapter(albatnaHospitals);

                } else if (materialDesignSpinner.getText().toString() == getString(R.string.musandam)) {

                    ArrayAdapter<String> smaelHospitals = new ArrayAdapter<>(v.getContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.musandam_hospitals));

                    materialDesignSpinner2.setAdapter(smaelHospitals);

                } else if (gm.spinnerChecking(materialDesignSpinner)) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), getString(R.string.choose_state_first), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                System.out.println("Working");
            }
        });
```

**when I press on the spinner, the application crashes**

showing the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Filter.filter(java.lang.CharSequence,
>   android.widget.Filter$FilterListener)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                 at
>   android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performFiltering(AutoCompleteTextView.java:971)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner.onFocusChanged(MaterialBetterSpinner.java:49)

how can I make the second spinner choices based on the first spinner?

**UPDATE:**

after applying @dominicoder solution, the `onItemSelected` is not executed for some reason because `System.out.println()` doesn't print "work" to the console.

Here is the code for the `onItemSelected` :

```
materialDesignSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                secondSpinnerAdapter.clear();
                secondSpinnerAdapter.addAll(getStringsForPosition(position));
                System.out.println("works");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Do *NOT* do string comparisons using `==` in Java. Use `String.equals()`
2. Use the *position* of the selection of the first spinner to determine what to show, not *the text* that happens to be showing in that position.
3. You should update the state of the second spinner *in response to* the changing of the state of the first spinner, not checking the first spinner state when it's time to show something in the second spinner
4. You should create just *one* adapter for your second spinner that you update as needed, instead of creating a new instance each time.

With these suggestions in mind, I would recommend something more like this:

```
// Second adapter is a class field
private ArrayAdapter<String> secondSpinnerAdapter;

// Initialize it ONCE in onCreate with no items to begin with
secondSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
materialDesignSpinner2.setAdapter(secondSpinnerAdapter);

// When something is selected in the first adapter,
// update the options in the second adapter
materialDesignSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        secondSpinnerAdapter.clear();
        secondSpinnerAdapter.addAll(getStringsForPosition(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});

private String[] getStringsForPosition(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 0: return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.musandam_hospitals);
        // Add other cases
    }
}
```

This eliminates string equality checks, removes duplication, and makes the intent "when something in the first spinner is a selected, update the options in the second spinner" much clearer.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, you also helped me write better code. :)

Comment: for some reason materialDesignSpinner2 content remains empty even after changing the position of the first spinner

Comment: when I added System.out.println("Checking"); inside onItemSelected nothing was printed to the console. seems that onItemSelected isn't working for some reason, do you know why? sorry for my questions

Comment: It would be hard to say without seeing some code. Make sure you're actually making a selection (and not selecting the thing already selected, for example)

Comment: I updated the question and added the onItemSelected code.

Comment: I accepted your answer, I found that the materialBetterSpinner is actually an EditText not a spinner and thats what caused onItemSelectedListener not to work. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't set an on click listener. instead of that do this

```
materialDesignSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Comment: if it is this way, I should implemented in the first spinner, am I right?

Comment: yes you should implement it like this @BehrouzRiahi